# How add a top-down page border?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

See the page border shown in image below

[Image link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApJrNqcv2bOEixpYL4OJgwaoQuiG)
(I was not able to post the image here due to not having enough reputations on this site. Sorry about that.)

In the above image, there is a page border consisting of a set of lines at top and bottom of the page. The set of line has one thick and one thin line placed one below the other at the top and bottom of the page. Also there is a margin for the border at both left and right. How do I add such a border to a set of pages in my word document.
Im on word 2013.

Comment: About the "top-down page border", do you mean the line in Header and Footer? If it is, you can directly double click header and footer in the document page. Then go to Insert > Shapes > Line. Draw a line in header. In the Format, you can click Shape Outline to set the weight of the line.

Comment: @WinniL Yes I mean the double line in header and footer. I think your comment can be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a paragraph border in the header and footer of each section where you want this to appear.

- Display Headers and Footers by typing "Headers and Footers" in the Tell Me box.
- Type "Borders and Shading" in the Tell Me bar to open the Borders and Shading dialog
- Refer to image ![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcpkz.jpg) for the correct settings.

Keep in mind that you need to apply this in each section of the document where you want this page border displayed.  If your sections are linked, then a change in the heaader or footer of one linked section will propagate to other linked sections.